# Can not import ibd to MariaDB 10.4 in xampp

Tags: backup, mariadb

I got a wordpress website, today it give me an error on xampp, I managed to re-install xampp, before this, I create a backup from `mysql/data` db folders, it contains `ibd` and `frm` files, I installed fresh xampp and I paste those db folders to `mysql/data` but when I open phpmyadmin it won't let open any tables and give me an error:

> #1932 - Table ... doesn't exist in engine

I googled about 3hrs and figured out I can restore lost data from ibd file, so I follow instruction from this **[article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61727167/import-ibd-files-into-mysql-server)** but after run `ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE;` it give me another error:

> internal error: Drop all secondary indexes before importing table

I am not MariaDB expert, I don't know how to restore my data, at least from `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` with these `ibd` files, I got very important data on this table, my bad is never run a sql backup before this happen! now I wondering if there is a way to restore data from those files or I failed? is there any hope?

I would be thankful for any help!

Comment: If you have the entire tree, not just a few .ibd files, then put all of them in place while MySQL is not running.

Comment: @RickJames I have all ibd files and I did what you said, but it give me error when click on tables `Table ... doesn't exist in engine` I wrote this in my question

Comment: MariaDB is not MySQL. MariaDB started as a fork of MySQL in 2010, but both products have changed a lot since then. You should not think of MariaDB as compatible with MySQL anymore. Any solution for one doesn't necessarily work for the other, so you must be clear about which one you use.

Comment: Information on [transportable tablespaces](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces/#copying-transportable-tablespaces). Hope you have backups now. Did you consider/try following the advice given "Drop all secondary indexes before importing table"?

Answer (score 0):

If you had *only* the .ibd files, then you are missing the vital .frm files -- these contain the table definitions.

The following *may* work (pre-8.0):

1. Remove the .ibd files
2. `CREATE TABLE` to reconstruct the schema.
3. Shutdown mysql.
4. Now reload the .ibd files, clobbering the stubs created by the `CREATEs`.  There may be a problem with "table numbers" somewhere.  (I forget the details.  Rummage around this forum; the problem is not a new one.)

Comment: I have all, `ibd` and also `frm`, your solution not working because after I put `ibd` files in place, when I open `phpmyadmin` it shows all tables but when I click it give me error: `'wp_posts' doesn't exist in engine`

Comment: @tourtravel - what version of MySQL?  8.0 needs a drastically different recovery approach.  (I don't know it.)

Comment: It's `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.27-MariaDB,`

Answer (score 0):

> internal error: Drop all secondary indexes before importing table

To do this, as you are doing it from scratch:

1. From the `CREATE TABLE` statement executed, omit all KEY creations except the `PRIMARY KEY` and run this.
2. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name DISCARD TABLESPACE`;
3. Copy the ibd file to table_name.ibd in the target location
4. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE`;
5. Run `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD KEY .... , ADD KEY` to add your secondary indexes.